# Como criar um dataframe copiando somente colunas escolhidas de outro dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Gostaria de criar um novo df a partir de um df inicial, somente com algumas colunas do df inicial, segue abaixo o código:

```
df_inicial = ['ABC', 'SPJ', 'GG']
```

Resultado:

```
ABC  SPJ  GG
6     2    3
1     3    5
5     2    5
3     1    8
3     0    1
```

Quero passar esse df para que o df_final fique dessa forma:

```
SPJ  GG
2    3
3    5
2    5
1    8
0    1
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras, entao vou expandir a sua resposta:

Primeiro sempre acho importante clonar um dataframe( se usar uma cópia e mudar a cópia, mudará a original também)

```
df_clone=df_inicial[:] #aqui usamos a funcao slice ou corte para selecionar todas as linhas
```

Agora com estes dados, voce pode usar os indexes das colunas para escolher as colunas (utilizando os nomes):

```
df_final=df_clone[['SPJ','GG']]
```

Dica: para visualizar os nomes das colunas: `df_clone.columns` - as vezes podem haver espacos no fim das expressoes (strings), por isso sempre cheque.

Outra alternativa é usar o `iloc` (parametros númericos, nao recomendo) ou o `.loc` parametros em texto.

A vantagem do `.loc` é a selecao de colunas inclusive a selecao de linhas:

```
df_clone.loc[:,['SPJ','GG']] #retorna o mesmo valor que antes
```

Caso voce queira só algumas linhas:

```
df_clone.loc[:2,['SPJ','GG']] # retorna da linha 0 até a linha 2
df_clone.loc[1:3,['SPJ','GG']] # retorna da linha 1 até a linha 3
df_clone.loc[::2,['SPJ','GG']] # retorna todas as linhas, em intervalos de dois--> apenas as pares
```

Muito importante: Se voce só chamar `df_clone['SPJ']`, **chaves simples**,  receberá apenas uma das colunas, MAS, está nao será mais um df, e sim uma pd.Series (outra biblioteca e outros comandos). Por isso, se quiser continuar trabalhando com dataframes, sempre **uses a chaves duplas** `df_clone[['SPJ']]`

compare  `type(df_clone[['SPJ']])` com `type(df_clone['SPJ'])`

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, ajudou muito!